# Weeding out duplicate Photos in a submission based photo contest

Tags: digital, duplicates

Scenario: Burger business holds an online photo contest that gives $1 off on a hamburger meal, to anyone submitting a photo of themselves, wearing printed t-shirt with a burger on it.

Is there a way to identify if a photo was used before.  The objective would be to have thousands and thousands of separate hamburger t-shirt pictures but no two pictures that are alike.

Wouldn't care what kind of burger as long as it is on the tshirt

Comment: I don't know of how to do it, but conceptually it is possible, as what you are asking for is basically what Google image search does - you give it a photo, and it tells you if it it is already online.  But IMHO this is more of a data processing rather than photography problem, so is not suited to *this* forum.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. The confirmation that it is possible will allow me to move forward and figure out the details later. Thanks Again i will be back on this forum for photo advice.

Comment: I've used a Windows application called VisiPics to identify duplicate images in the past, so programmatic identification of duplicates seems to be something that was solved long ago.

Answer (score 3):

This is not really a photography question. It is possible to do such things, but it is really a software engineering and artificial intelligence problem that has little to do with photography by itself.

I would suggest starting your research by looking at [PhotoDNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhotoDNA), which is what a lot of websites use to detect images that they do not allow on their platform.

Answer (score 0):

In photography, as long as each person takes a new photo, even if it is of a similar subject, it is still a new photo and the photographer cannot be faulted for repeating the content!  As a business owner and issuer of the call, you must place a specific and variable physical sign on the objects in front of the lens when staging the scene for photography, so that no two photos are alike.